# Set bsButton position in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinybs

I have a basic shiny dashboard below and I would like to know if I can a little bit left or right the bs button "show/hide sidebar".

```
#ui.r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'testingDPEtab',
      tabPanel("Upload",
               bsButton("showpanel8", "Show/Hide sidebar",icon = icon("toggle-off"), type = "toggle",style = "info", value = TRUE),
               dashboardPage(
                 dashboardHeader(),
                 dashboardSidebar(),
                 dashboardBody())

    )
  )
))
#server.r
server <- function(input, output) { }
```

Comment: only the button or also the upload button and the blue area below?

Comment: the button. I think that the "blue area" is the sidebar and cannot be moved if Im not mistaken

Comment: I want a button with that name that will place a big red X over stuff I click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to apply the "moving" to a specific button or for all these buttons you can do:

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML('#showpanel8{margin-left:10px}'))
)
```

Here, the button is referenced by id. So the change will only apply to that button.
`#showpanel8{margin-left:10px}` is CSS syntax to style the button.
For other margins you can use:

- margin-top
- margin-right
- margin-bottom
- margin-left

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp.

**Full reproducible example:**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML('#showpanel8{margin-left:10px}'))
    ),
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'testingDPEtab',
      tabPanel("Upload",
               bsButton("showpanel8", "Show/Hide sidebar",
                        icon = icon("toggle-off"), type = "toggle",
                        style = "info", value = TRUE),
               dashboardPage(
                 dashboardHeader(),
                 dashboardSidebar(),
                 dashboardBody())

      )
    )
))
#server.r
server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```